# Hadoop error when trying to initiate start-dfs.sh on linux (pop_os 22.04)

Tags: linux, hadoop, installation

I installed the latest hadoop package (3.3.6). I was also following the installation procedure listed in the official [apache hadoop website](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html), and [this medium article](https://medium.com/@festusmorumbasi/installing-hadoop-on-ubuntu-20-04-4610b6e0391e)(I didn't create a separate user called hadoop as listed in the medium article).

Everything was set and I also configured the parameters properly as per the instruction, but when i tried to initiate start-dfs.sh I am facing this particular issue.

```
start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: ERROR: Cannot set priority of namenode process 5746
Starting datanodes
localhost: ERROR: Cannot set priority of datanode process 5872
Starting secondary namenodes [pop-os]
pop-os: ERROR: Cannot set priority of secondarynamenode process 6036
```

I tried multiple things like using sudo, changing the configuration for namenode and datanode, using openssh, and many more.

I would really appreaciate if someone can at least tell me what's going wrong. If any configuration files or log files are needed, I can provide it.

Comment: Are you using Java 11? Review fully distributed setup for how Hadoop is actually meant to be ran https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html And yes, you should create unique OS users for Hadoop and YARN processes

Comment: @OneCricketeer I used open-jdk-8, so I assume java configuration is not the issue. As for creating a separate user for hadoop, I still do not understand the significance behind it.

Comment: Hadoop supports Java 11 now, since 3.2, I think. And users are for process isolation and security best practice. It's not unique to hadoop.... If you ran a mysql server or http server, you'd want to create unique users for each... More specifically, yarn (mapreduce) can execute random shell commands, submitted to your cluster, and Hadoop is not secure by default. Many hadoop clusters across the world have been hacked because root user was given permission to run anything (this is also why not to use sudo)